# HTML5 semantic tag usage, will search engines respect large wrapping?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

I was planning to use the `<nav>` tag for a few things, however, the following occurred to me.

Take the following markup for example:

```
<nav id="sidebar">

<div class="links">
<a href="/"></a>
<a href="/"></a>
<a href="/"></a>
</div>


<div class="links">
<a href="/"></a>
<a href="/"></a>
</div>


<div class="links">
<a href="/"></a>
</div>

<div class="statement">
random content here, unrelated to navigation
</div>

<div class="randomstuff">
unrelated to navigation, but still here
</div>

</nav>
```

Will search engines respect this sort of usage of semantic tags? By that I mean, "ignore" or lower the priority on all content that's wrapped with a nav tag(even divs and such), even if not directly, or even necessarily all navigational content.

Same question for `header` and `footer` tags with `div`s inside.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If anyone tells you how search engines work they are lying or violating a non-disclosure agreement.  Those algorithms are very confidential and are actually dynamic to prevent them from being reverse engineered.

Comment: I wasn't being that specific. Nothing is flawless. However, those semantic tags do help, and I just wanted to hear if anyone knew additional information on the rules that apply to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't include content in `nav` that is not about navigation. Not only the spec is [very clear](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) about it, it would harm accessibility, too.

So your two `div` elements (`.statement` and `.randomstuff`) need to get out of the `nav` element. Only if they'd be "tangentially related" to the content in `nav`, you could put the two elements in an [`aside` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element) inside of`nav`, but I don't think this is the case for your content.

> May I ask what HTML5 tag you'd recommend for general page content that is included on each page but isn't navigation? Serving the same purpose as header, footer, and nav, deterring inclusion in results since it's general and on each page.

There is no general answer; it depends on your content which element should be used.

You create the overall structure (the document outline) by using the sectioning elements (`section`, `article`, `nav`, `aside`) and headings. Now each section (not to be confused with `section` element!) *can* have `header`/`footer` elements. That's it. Everything inside a section that is not included in `header`/`footer` can be considered the main content *of that section*. Finer grained elements like `address` or `small` can give additional clues which role their content plays.

Now, if something (a search engine, a screenreader, an artifial intelligence, …) wants to consume your document, it might take advantage of your markup. If and to what extent this is the case depends on several factors, like use case, will, skill, costs, etc. So there is no general answer to "Do search engines …?", because *a)* there are *countless* search engines (and everyone can create a new one everyday) and *b)* some (especially the "big players" for general web search) don't like to talk in details about this stuff.

But we can *assume* what would be useful for all those user-agents/consumers in respect to their use cases:

- a screenreader might offer a function to only read the main content (ignoring `nav`, `aside`, `footer`, …)
- a blog post search engine might score words inside `article` higher than inside `nav`/`aside`
- a search engine might score words in `header`, `footer`, `small` and `address` *higher* for a navigational search query, and *lower* for a research query
- a readibility add-on might try to find the main content by ignoring `nav`, `footer` and top-level `aside` elements
- …

HTML defines the meaning of all elements. If all HTML authors would respect this, we could build and use user-agents that make perfect use of the markup. In reality though, authors might (mis-)use `nav` to "devalue" boilerplate content ☺, which would force all consuming user-agents to forget about the special meaning of `nav` (because it might contain other, non-navigational content, that could be important for their use case).

Comment: Wow, first, thank you very much for going into such detail. As for .statement, and .randomstuff. Let's say they're just social widgets or content included on each page that would be ideally not focused on. Such as security seals and such which are not always necessarily generated with js. It sounds like aside would be the ideal tag for them though.

Comment: @popsicle: Yes, `aside` could be appropriate for a security seal (but `footer` might be better suited), but this `aside` should not be a child of `nav`, but instead a child of the section that is relevant to the security sign (→ if the sign certifies the *whole page*, the `aside` should be a child of `body`). For social widgets, I'd say they belong in a `footer`. If they are related to the whole page, place them in the `footer` of the `body`. If they belong to a certain blog post only, place them in the `footer` of that `article`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all any content that is unrelated to navigation should not be contained within a `nav` tag.

As for what search engines will do with such content should you (or anyone else) have such incorrect markup is anyone's guess.

Short answer: Nobody knows!

Comment: I see. May I ask what HTML5 tag you'd recommend for general page content that is included on each page but isn't navigation? Serving the same purpose as header, footer, and nav, deterring inclusion in results since it's general and on each page.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make semantic sense to use NAV around a whole block. Use a generic DIV for layout purposes.

For semantic purposes, you could use multiple NAV elements for sets of links, but the spec is pretty open, so make of it what you will:

```
<div id="sidebar">

<nav>
<div class="links">
<a href="/"></a>
<a href="/"></a>
<a href="/"></a>
</div>
</nav>

<nav>
<div class="links">
<a href="/"></a>
<a href="/"></a>
</div>
</nav>

<nav>
<div class="links">
<a href="/"></a>
</div>
</nav>

<section>
<div class="statement">
random content here, unrelated to navigation
</div>

<div class="randomstuff">
unrelated to navigation, but still here
</div>
</section>

</div>
```

You just need to honestly ask yourself, "does this read logically?".

Truth is, there's a lot of **HYPE** about HTML5 tags. Personally, I think they're a great idea, but in practice, it's only guess work right now as to what search engines do with them.

Hope this helps.
Mikey

Comment: There is no problem in using `nav` for a "whole block", as all the `div` elements have no meaning anyway (of course everything inside should be navigational content). But splitting this up and using several `nav` elements creates an document outline you probably don't want.

Comment: Well, this is the problem...their usage is so ambiguous. To me, it seems as though content not designed for 'navigation' should therefore NOT be in a nav tag at all.

Comment: Yes, that should not be in the `nav`. But I mean those `div` elements with the `links` class -- it's totally fine to include all those in *one* `nav` element (instead of using a separate `nav` element for each)